# Setting imageIcon without full path

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, embedded-resource

I'm trying to st the icon on a Jlabel but I get "NullPointerException" every time I run it. It does run while I put in the full path but I don't want to do that because I want to move the java programme around the environment.

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/data/images/image.jpg")));
```

I believe the problem is in the path I'm trying to use.

My rough project environment is:

```
projectfolder/src
projectfolder/data/images/image.jpg
```

I've tried using:

```
/image.jpg
/data/images/image.jpg
data/images/image.jpg
.\\data\\images\\image.jpg
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The file needs to be in your classpath.

Comment: it is, I was just using "path" to complete the example, I'll correct to prevent confusion.

Comment: Prove us that it is in the classpath. What's the command line used to start the application?

Comment: @JBNizet what do you mean, start the application? I have a Jlist of names linked to images that when I click on one it changes the image. I've got the links to the image getting the icon to change that is the problem.

Comment: camickr told you that the file needed to be in the classpath. You answered: "it is". So that means that when you start the application (because you start it, right, otherwise, how could it run), you specify what the classpath is, and in that classpath, the directory containing the file is present. So, show us how you start the application. Prove us that the file is indeed in the classpath. You should know that, since you said "it is".

Comment: well when the programme is started the icon is empty and I've checked that yes from the data folder everything is there, but I don't want to define the rest of the path directly because it won't work on someone else's computer. Does it have to be inside the SRC folder or something?

Comment: It has to be in the runtime classpath. The easiest way to achieve that is indeed to put in under src, since your IDE will "compile" everyting from this folder to the output directory, which in turn is in the runtime classpath when the IDE starts the application. It seems you have no idea what the classpath is, since you refuse to answer my question: how do you start the application, and what is its runtime classpath? But then, why do you tell camickr that it is in the classpath if you have no idea. Answering "I don't know" would have been fine.

Comment: @JBNizet so the full classpath would be: C:\Users\myname\workspace\project\data\AlbumArtwork\image.jpg But I don't want to have the classpath but that since it will break if I move it over to another computer. So all I want to put in is: \data\AlbumArtwork\image.jpg

Comment: Take a huge step back, and learn what the classpath is. In the meantime, just move the data directory to src, and use the code that you posted in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Class#getResource()` returns the resource relative to your class' location. Use `ClassLoader#getResource()` instead. If using the default class loader, it returns the resource relative to the classpath of your program.

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("data/images/image.jpg")
```

You should place your data folder inside the `src` folder. Otherwise the data folder is not contained in the program's `.jar`.

Comment: No, it doesn't when the path starts with a slash. And It should NOT start with a slash if using getCLassLoader().getResource(). And no, it doesn't return resources relative to the executation location of your program. It loads resources from the classpath.